# Wordpress SQL console error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

My error log stated this error:

> \xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x88\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 INSERT INTO `wp_anti_haxtool` (`anti_haxtool_signature_id`, `anti_haxtool_name`, `anti_haxtool_signature`, `anti_haxtool_type`, `anti_haxtool_risk`,`anti_haxtool_status`) VALUES \r, referer: http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php

Please help me fix it. I am new to phpmyadmin and I am not sure how to fix the error.

I have one more error also in the error log:

> \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8a\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 activate_plugins, activate_plugin, do_action('activate_anti-hacking-tools/anti_haxtool.php'), call_user_func_array, _anti_haxtool_activate, referer: http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php

I am using Wordpress with theme Avada. All the CSS cool looking functions stopped working probably because of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate your anti-hax tool plugin. It is throwing error.

Comment: thanks, i did deactivate this plugin, but it didnt start working properly in the front end yet - it stays the same.  So the problem in my lack of effect must be from somewhere else- eny suggestions?

Comment: my website is here: http://lipoin.com/otslabvane/  - there is a problem in loading the pictures also some effects like that blue zeros must be like 50- 100 , not zero. it starts from zero and ends in another number. its may be animations

Comment: zero's are there I can see. but where is the error ? where did you set the numbers ?

Comment: well its an animations i think , all of them dont work, also the pictures dont load- see the empty places, there must be a pictures. :(

Comment: Your site doesn't have any JS error. It seems something screwed in PHP itself. And as a site visitor, I can't guess PHP code :(

Comment: humm well any suggestions what i can replace/change so it could get fixed on its own or anything that i can do that could help at all?
i did till now like everything i thinked of :(

Comment: see that portion is added in your theme by theme code or plugin ? If plugin then try to uninstall and install again. If you have any data/settings of that plugin then try to delete all of them and try afresh. But if it is in template and written directly then get help from a developer.  By the way if you can remember when it first occured ? was it working previously ? if yes then try to revert changes after that and then try one by one :)

Comment: well thanks - ill tell you what happens after i check all things again

Comment: updated the theme and its fixed now- thanks for your help  u were really helpful mate.
thanks a lot!